# How to force download of an .mp4 file by PHP headers from external url?

Tags: php, curl, header, web-scraping

I was unable to find an answer regarding headers. I have a .MP4 file hosted on website *A* and would like to force download using a button on website *B*. Is it possible without downloading the file to website B and then serving it to the user?

I have already pulled all the necessary data to website B, but in order to download a file, the user needs to right click to save on the button.

Comment: on page on server B add link to file on server A. if you need you can use CSS to make it looks like button.

Comment: So far this trick just plays the Video in the browser instead of downloading it :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rpowis/4667115

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use (PHP) where $cf contains the path to the file being requested.  You may want a download script stored on server B that makes this happen and just link to the script to do the download .. http://link.to.script/script.php?file=thefilename.mp4'>Download  I wouldn't normally put the filename in the URL but this is just an example.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($cf) . '"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($cf));
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
readfile(realpath($cf));
```

Comment: Website A uses javascript to produce the jwplayer and url. I have grabbed the url and necessary data but just cannot force it to download instead of playing in the browser.